# MonoTouch: Bundle Name Not Being Displayed Under Icon

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, bundle

I would like to use a shorter version of my app's name for display under the icon. I have read that the Bundle Name is the value that displays this shortened name. I added the Bundle Name (CFBundleName) to my info.plist, but my app's name is still being displayed according to the Bundle Display Name (CFBundleDisplayName). Am I missing something here? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try with metadata->title key:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>items</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>assets</key>
            <array>
                <dict>
                    <key>kind</key>
                    <string>software-package</string>
                    <key>url</key>
                    <string>http://www.example.es/YourAppBundle.ipa</string>
                </dict>
            </array>
            <key>metadata</key>
            <dict>
                <key>bundle-identifier</key>
                <string>XXXXXXXXXX</string>
                <key>kind</key>
                <string>software</string>
                <key>title</key>
                <string>YourAppName</string>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```